# Thread safety for reference types without using synchronized

Tags: java, concurrency

I have the following class, which should be thread-safe:

```
public class ShouldBeMadeThreadSafe {

    private double[] k = {70.0,70.0}; 
    private double[] b = {10.0,10.0};
    private double[] m = {5.0,6.0};

    public synchronized void setKX(double kx) {k[0]=kx;}
    public synchronized void setKY(double ky) {k[1]=ky;}
    public synchronized void setBX(double bx) {b[0]=bx;}
    public synchronized void setBY(double by) {b[1]=by;}
    public synchronized void setMX(double mx) {m[0]=mx;}
    public synchronized void setMY(double my) {m[1]=my;}

    public double[] getK() {return Arrays.copyOf(k, k.length);}
    public double[] getB() {return Arrays.copyOf(b, b.length);}
    public double[] getM() {return Arrays.copyOf(m, m.length);}

}
```

This, of course, has visibility problems in the getters, because a happens-before relationship is only guaranteed between the unlocking and locking of a monitor.

The obvious fix would be to add the synchronized keyword to the getters:

```
public class OkButIDontLikeDeadlocks {

    private double[] k = {70.0,70.0}; 
    private double[] b = {10.0,10.0};
    private double[] m = {5.0,6.0};

    public synchronized void setKX(double kx) {k[0]=kx;}
    public synchronized void setKY(double ky) {k[1]=ky;}
    public synchronized void setBX(double bx) {b[0]=bx;}
    public synchronized void setBY(double by) {b[1]=by;}
    public synchronized void setMX(double mx) {m[0]=mx;}
    public synchronized void setMY(double my) {m[1]=my;}

    public synchronized double[] getK() {return Arrays.copyOf(k, k.length);}
    public synchronized double[] getB() {return Arrays.copyOf(b, b.length);}
    public synchronized double[] getM() {return Arrays.copyOf(m, m.length);}

}
```

I'm not a fan of this one because this way I'm invoking an alien method with a lock held, which is asking for possible deadlocks. Maybe that's not the case here, but even then I don't think it's elegant enough (correct me please if I'm wrong).

Now I was wondering if the following would be thread-safe:

```
public class AmIThreadSafe {

    private volatile double[] k = {70.0,70.0}; 
    private volatile double[] b = {10.0,10.0};
    private volatile double[] m = {5.0,6.0};

    public void setKX(double kx) {k[0]=kx;}
    public void setKY(double ky) {k[1]=ky;}
    public void setBX(double bx) {b[0]=bx;}
    public void setBY(double by) {b[1]=by;}
    public void setMX(double mx) {m[0]=mx;}
    public void setMY(double my) {m[1]=my;}

    public double[] getK() {return Arrays.copyOf(k, k.length);}
    public double[] getB() {return Arrays.copyOf(b, b.length);}
    public double[] getM() {return Arrays.copyOf(m, m.length);}

}
```

I don't think it is because I'm not rewriting the volatile reference itself.

So, what would be the best way to make ShouldBeMadeThreadSafe thread-safe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have misunderstood the advice not to call alien code holding a lock. `Arrays.copyOf` *is not alien code*: it is a precisely identified, precisely specified method of the JDK. The case with alien code would be something like this:

```
public synchronized double[] getK(Runnable r) { r.run(); return k; };
```

Here you are executing the `run` method of a completely unknown class, which may as well call one of your other methods, destroying the invariants.

It is perfectly fine to use `synchronized` on all methods; and yes, `volatile` won't help you.

Comment: I have accepted this answer because it focuses on the cause of my asking this question, which was a misunderstanding of what is meant by "alien code".

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that this is not thread-safe, for the reason you give.

Your three main options are:

- `synchronize` the getters and setters (as in your post)
- write to the `volatile` references in the setters; `setKY(double ky) {k[1]=ky; k = k;}`
- use [AtomicLongArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLongArray.html), which gives you CAS-like accessors to array elements, including memory visibility. You can convert the doubles to and from longs using [Double.doubleToLongBits](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToLongBits%28double%29)

I would go for the first, to be honest. It's simplest, and the actions are going to be so quick that synchronization isn't likely to be a bottleneck.

Comment: Could you please explain what CAS-like accessors are? I've googled a little bit but got no answer.

Comment: @deinocheirus CAS lets you atomically say "if the value is X, set it to Y; otherwise don't change it. Let me know if the change succeeded." But in addition to that fanciness, which you don't need for this, it also has memory visibility semantics the same as a `volatile`: see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html